# Can HTTP::Tiny be used to upload files?

Tags: perl

Can `HTTP::Tiny` be used to upload files?  Nothing in the [HTTP::Tiny docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) or any of the examples I can find via google show how to upload files with this Perl module.  Is it possible?  Are there any better `HTTP::Tiny` examples?

Comment: Not really, no. The point of `HTTP::Tiny` is largely just to be a minimal enough implementation of an HTTP client that can live in perl core, so that `CPAN.pm` can work to pull a better one off CPAN. It exists largely for bootstrapping purposes, and any task outside of this goal isn't really within its remit.

Comment: @LeoNerd any recommendations for modules that do support multipart file upload?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny::Multipart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not easily.  HTTP::Tiny contains no support for the `multipart/form-data` content type required by file uploads.  (That's one of the reasons it's called "Tiny".)

You *could* upload a file using the `request` method, but you'd have to supply the encoded `content` yourself and also add a `multipart/form-data` content-type header.

This would be something like

```
$response = $tiny->request('POST', $url, {
        content => $multipart_form_data,
        headers => {'content-type' => 'multipart/form-data'},
    }
);
```

Correctly populating `$multipart_form_data` is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: This answer may be outdated, see [post_form](https://perldoc.perl.org/HTTP::Tiny#post_form)

Comment: This answer is still valid for posting JSON.